# How to block WordPress oEmbed HTTP URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

Want to block oEmbed requests that contain non-https URLs, but following code isn't helping me. Not sure if this is even the right hook. Any ideas?

```
add_filter('pre_oembed_result', array($this, 'filter_oembed'), 5, 3);

function filter_oembed ($result, $url, $args) {
    if (substr($url, 0, 7) === "http://") {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using Wordpress 4.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a lot of Wordpress experience, but [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_oembed_result/) make it sound like it's expecting some kind of return, and you only return when the URL starts with "http://". Also, I assume this is running in some sort of class, otherwise using `$this` in the callback spec wouldn't work well. By the way, PHP provides [a built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse a URL:

```
<?php
add_filter('pre_oembed_result', array($this, 'filter_oembed'), 5, 3);

function filter_oembed ($result, $url, $args) {
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) !== "https") {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Disable oEmbed for a Single Shortcode or at Least All Internal Links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233045/65415) may also shed more light on things.

Comment: Thanks link you included helped .. In your answer it should be return false instead of return null!